# Fast implementation of incrementing dates by days according to another column pandas

Tags: pandas, datetime

I have the following pandas DF:

```
print(df.to_dict())
{'Date_Installed': {11885: Timestamp('2018-11-15 00:00:00'), 111885: Timestamp('2018-11-15 00:00:00')}, 'days_from_instalation': {11885: 2, 111885: 3}}
```

I would like to create a new column that increments the `'Date_Installed'` column by the days from the column `'days_from_instalation'`

I know that this is possible using the `apply()` method as following:

```
from datetime import timedelta
df['desired_date']=df.apply(lambda row:row['Date_Installed']+timedelta(row['days_from_instalation']), axis=1)
```

which produces my desired output:

```
print(df.to_dict())

{'Date_Installed': {11885: Timestamp('2018-11-15 00:00:00'), 111885: Timestamp('2018-11-15 00:00:00')}, 'days_from_instalation': {11885: 2, 111885: 3}, 'desired_date': {11885: Timestamp('2018-11-17 00:00:00'), 111885: Timestamp('2018-11-18 00:00:00')}}
```

However this method is extremely slow, and isn't realistic to apply to my full DF.

I wen't over several questions on incrementing dates in pandas like this one:

[pandas-increment-datetime](http://https:/stackoverflow.com/questions/38242692/pandas-increment-datetime)

But they all seem to deal with constant incrementation, without any vectorised method to do so.

Is there any vectorised version of this type of increment?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add timedeltas created by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
df['desired_date'] = df['Date_Installed'] +
                        pd.to_timedelta(df['days_from_instalation'], unit='d')

print (df)
       Date_Installed  days_from_instalation desired_date
11885      2018-11-15                      2   2018-11-17
111885     2018-11-15                      3   2018-11-18
```

Another numpy solution is faster, but lost timezones (if specified):

```
a = pd.to_timedelta(df['days_from_instalation'], unit='d').values.astype(np.int64)
df['desired_date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Installed'].values.astype(np.int64)+a, unit='ns')
```

**Performance**:

```
#20krows
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)

In [217]: %timeit df['desired_date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Installed'].values.astype(np.int64) + pd.to_timedelta(df['days_from_instalation'], unit='d').values.astype(np.int64), unit='ns')
886 µs ± 9.92 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [218]: %timeit df['desired_date'] = df['Date_Installed'] + pd.to_timedelta(df['days_from_instalation'], unit='d')
1.53 ms ± 82.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```